# Cyclocross frame size question

Tags: frames, cyclocross

I'm looking to purchase my first cyclocross bike and just found a good deal from someone. It's a Cannondale CAADX tiagra 2015 with a frame size of 56 cm (top tube 56cm basically). I'm a little bit afraid it might be too big for me. My height is 180 cm (5'11) with an inseam of 82 cm. Do you think it would be too big for me, especially on long rides?

From what I've read, it seems that a 54cm frame would be much better for me, but this is a real good deal.

I can't test the bike, because the guy lives in another city.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles . We recommend that new members [take the tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to get to know how to make best use of the site. Please use the [search function](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=frame+size) before posting questions, and read through some of the answers that pop up. That way if you still need help you can show us what you've already learned, and we can help fill in the missing details.

Comment: Honestly?  Sounds like a good reason for a road trip.  Take the bus/train/hitch there, try the bike, and if you don't like it don't buy it.  Then you can ride it home.  Bikes are like shoes because fit is EVERYTHING, and buying sight-unseen is asking for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you step over the top tube without doing extreme acrobatics?-- if so, the height shouldn't be a problem; [The length of the top tube (i.e. how long the bike frame is rather than how tall) is the more pertinent question](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-sizing.html). I can't say either "yes" or "no" to "is this frame too big?" in this regard because people's dimensions vary widely anyway: I'm also 180cm and supposedly have relatively long legs according to some "professional bike fitting charts" (but I doubt that my legs are in fact longer than most — see e.g. [a sizing chart from ebicycles](http://www.ebicycles.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ebicycles-bicycle-sizing-chart-road-bikes.pdf)) for someone my height and most 55-56cm top-tubed frames fit me more or less okay but your legs may be shorter or longer than mine, meaning you'd need a shorter or longer frame length to accommodate it.

If you can't get (unbiased) professional fitting advice, try doing some "real" riding the bike and see if the posture is comfortable, especially when doing turns (both leaning-style turns and turns using the handlebars): If it fits reasonably well and the price is good enough, you can easily tweak the dimensions using handlebar and saddle adjustments and/or replacements.